# How to make span left-aligned to its parent

Tags: css

How can I make the following span to be left-aligned with its parent, in this case, the DIV with id of “rightPanel”?

Currently, the following code displays the span content to the right with Safari browser.

```
<div id="rightPanel">
<span style="background-color:##ACE1AF; white-space:nowrap;">
my stuff goes here...
</span>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following CSS:

```css
#rightPanel {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Or, if you want to use inline styles (not recommended) as you did in your span tag:

```
<div id="rightPanel" style="text-align: left">
```

Comment: Great, thanks. But now, I have another problem.  The following inline CSS code fails with Safari browser on Windows (ver 5.1.7) while the same CSS code works fine with Chrome and Firefox.                       <input type="button" value="myfunc1" onclick="window.open('scirptX','createSTUFF','width=700,height='+(screen.height-150)+',resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');" style="transform: scaleX(0.8) scaleY(0.8);">

Comment: Ok, I voted up your answer.  Any button for [Accept] or the like?  Thanks.

Comment: Click the checkbox to the left of the answer to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh man, initially I thought it's a down arrow!  Thanks!  And I've posted the new question.